# iOS - Why is it ok that not declare IBAction methods in the header file?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I was learning [Start Developing iOS Apps Today](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW7), I noticed this method `unwindToList:` which has the return type of `IBAction` do not need to be declared in the header file first to pass the compilation or to run correctly. Since I can use any name I would like to as the method name, I think this is nothing to do with protocol.

Here is the example code:

**XYZToDoListViewController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XYZToDoListViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

**XYZToDoListViewController.m**:

```
@implementation XYZToDoListViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

}

// other implementations..

@end
```

After this, in the Interface Builder, as shown in the image below, I can control-drag a control to the exit icon to register this method as the action of the control. To my surprise, no error occurred after I clicked the Run button.

I'm new to Obj-C, this was kind of blowed my mind. I know a little about C. In C I must acknowledge compiler every function by declaring it or defining it before using it.

So I created a small project to see if I can define a method without declaration first in Obj-C.  Here is the code I tested:

```
// XYZFoo.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZFoo : NSObject

@end
```

The .m file:

```
// XYZFoo.m
#import "XYZFoo.h"

@implementation XYZFoo
- (void)bar {
    NSLog(@"hello, world");
}
@end
```

The main.m file:

```
// main.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XYZFoo.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        XYZFoo *foo = [[XYZFoo alloc] init];
        [foo bar];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This time I got an error. I can only fix it by adding the declaration in the header file. So in this case the declaration is required (of course).

There must be something I'm not familiar with happened behind the scene. Can anyone explain the mechanism behind this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: rewrite the question to get reps to obtain the magic voting power so that I can up vote or down vote other people's answer.

[image: drag to exit icon]

Comment: @Unheilig oh yes. In the tutorial I linked, it uses storyboard.

Comment: There is no IBAction in the code

Comment: @vikingosegundo There is a method whose return type is `IBAction` in the link I posted.

Comment: Please don't expect us to follow any link you posted. Your question should be integral in the meaning of complete. If you post an example make it the correct example.

Comment: @vikingosegundo the example has some images. I've linked the exact section of the tutorial which only has 4 paragraphs to read which I think won't cost people who can help me more than 2 minutes. I think stackoverflow provide link syntax for a reason.

Comment: This is not about believing. It is just expected that no one needs to navigate away or download something.

Comment: @vikingosegundo well, since this site provides the syntax of links. I think there must be some people would like to click links in posts and read the content. And some people may just more careful with clicking a link to "navigate away".

Comment: @Jox, what do u want me to say? I just tell you, how this community works. there is no need to discuss it further. if you want good answers, provide a good question.

Comment: And if you mention `IBAction` even in the title, but I can't find any in the sample code this is clearly an indication for a not good question.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I think I got two good answers. Maybe my question is not that good. But I don't think it's that bad either. right?

Comment: if it was too bad I would had voted for closure. But you should keep in mind to include anything important in your question in the future.

Comment: @vikingosegundo dude I've added the content of the link. maybe you can take back your downvote(if so?) so that I can have right to upvote other people's answer? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not generate declarations for actions. Here is what happens: when you connect a control to an action Interface Builder records information about the action selector in the storyboard.

When views from the storyboad are being instantiated storyboard runtime calls `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method of the newly created controls to connect them to there targets (see this link for details https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW8). The storyboard runtime uses storyboard file contents to connect actions hence it doesn't need the method declaration.

On the other hand when a method is called from outside of the class compiler checks if the method has been declared somewhere in the header files and issues *warning* if it doesn't find declaration to prevent possible runtime error.

Comment: Thanks. As I know, it's the UIApplication object reads the storyboard file to initialize views and view controllers. What do you mean by "storyboard runtime"?

Comment: I meant the code that reads storyboard contents and instantiates corresponding objects (basically `UIStoryboard` class).

Comment: It would be interesting to know from the person who down voted the answer what is wrong with it.

Comment: I guess it's the guy who downvoted my question. Apparently my question is not a good question. :)

Comment: Don't take it to heart, it's all subjective :) There are many bad questions here and your question is not that bad, I personally do not agree with him.

Comment: well, I understand. No big deal. And I've edited it again to try to make the question better. Hope to help people who happens meet same problem as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode isn't related to this by any means.

What happens is that in your code, you are explicitly calling the method on the object, by the standard bracket notation. You are telling the compiler that there's a method with a certain name (known at compile time), and you want to send that exact message to the object. For that, the compiler needs the declaration, of course.

However, when you are referring to an `IBAction`, I assume you mean callback methods which are called by various UI objects such as buttons or controls. (After having a quick look at Apple's documentation, I found that this method is called by the "Cancel" button.)

Those methods are invoked using some other mechanism, with the help of a feature of Objective-C called reflection, which makes it possible to call dynamically named methods at runtime. For example, I can imagine that somewhere in the `UIControl` class (the superclass of `UIButton`), there's an internal method that handles the dispatching of all actions like this:

```
- (void)dispatchActions
{
    for (id target in self.targets) {
        SEL selector = [self selectorForTarget:target]; // an imaginary method...
        [target performSelector:selector withObject:self];
    }
}
```

So this would use `performSelector:withObject:` to send all the messages to targets, completely dynamically. To do that, declaring the methods is not necessary, since **the compiler doesn't really see them being called.** It's just the runtime that is asked to send a message. All the compiler needs is the signature of the `performSelector:withObject:` method, which is available.

Comment: Thanks. In the apple's doc, the method is defined in the implementation file of view controller class. Since I'm new to objective-c, I can't fully understand terms like reflection in your post. If `IBAction` method do not need to be declared first, can I just define it in any place? Why is it defined in the view controller file, not other places?

Comment: @Jox I don't know why it's defined exactly there -- I haven't gone through the full code, and it's irrelevant anyway. And `IBAction`s aren't special either -- really, you can do this with methods of any other return type so long as you are using dynamic dispatch for calling them.

Comment: Nice explanation. The term "reflection" somehow rings a bell in Java for me. I wonder if they have any historical connection to each other, for that I meant Objective-C and Java in terms of "reflection".

Comment: @H2CO3 It seems xcode need `IBAction` when scanning the code. Otherwise, I can't link the method with a button in Interface Builder. What the tutorial does is: it defines a method whose return type is `IBAction`. and control-drag a button in Interface Builder to Exit (which has a green icon in the outline mode), then a black menu popped up which has an item that is the name of the `IBAction` method.

Comment: @Unheilig As a rough approximation, "reflection" refers to pretty much the same thing -- run-time, dynamic introspection (and manipulation) of classes and objects.

Comment: @Jox Maybe -- I don't use Xcode so I have to believe that. `IBAction` is just defined to `void` (I don't remember anymore if it is a preprocessor macro or a `typedef`); why `Xcode` needs it to be `IBAction` and not `void` is really because it scans the source files for `IBAction`s and it assumes that UI callback will be declared as such. Not very wise, but that's how Apple's engineers decided it to be.

Comment: @H2CO3 Just curiosity, what other IDE (if not Xcode) do you use for your Objective-C / iPhone coding adventure?

Comment: @Unheilig I'm using Gedit to write the code, and the `make` utility for build automation.

Comment: @H2CO3 Is there a reason why you don't use Xcode? Again, just curiosity.

Comment: @Unheilig Yes, I find it huge (it consumes a lot of memory, I mean **a lot**), hopelessly slow, annoying ("please confirm that you really wanted to type `int main()`"), overly complicated, and yet not flexible enough. UI fail, user experience fail, usability fail, everything fail. I have pretty much the same opinion about all popular IDEs nowadays. (And I'm especially disappointed that even Apple couldn't get their knowledge together and make a proper IDE. They made the same level of cr*p Microsoft had with Visual Studio.)

Comment: Controls do not call performSelector to call action method. Intead they call `UIApplication`s  `sendAction:to:from:forEvent:`.

Comment: @yurish That's very well possible. (You see, I've just whipped up a quick example that may help understanding the problem, and I've stated that it's an imaginary situation. That doesn't change anything, though.)

Comment: @Unheilig I do have a blog, but so far I've only written about personal things... in Hungarian! But indeed, maybe I should start blogging about tech stuff as well.

Comment: I just read the UIControl Class Reference. It has some explanation that helps me to understand this question. I think @yurish's answer is better. But many many many thanks to H2CO3 too. Thanks for your patience and your answer really somehow helps me to understand.

Comment: @H2CO3 The reason it is defined in the implementation of that class is that the method need information(a private property which keeps track of an array defined in the extension of the class) holded by the instance of the class. Xcode does the record work (record into the storyboard file as yurish said). And it's the view object and UIApplication object dispatch events to the target. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to control-drag from buttons to their actions, then you **DO** need to define the IBAction in the header. The "IBAction" keyword in the method declaration (in the header) tells IB about the methods that are available to connect as actions. Without an IBAction declaration, IB doesn't know about the method.

Usually when you try to call a method in another class that is defined in the .m file but not the .h file, you get a warning, not an error. If you ignore the warning (a bad idea) then at runtime the code still works because the method does exist.

Objective C uses runtime binding, so method calls aren't resolved until execution time.

Comment: You don't need to define outlets and actions in the header file. Implementation file is enough (class extention or implementation section).

Comment: you also can control-drag to an action declared in a class extension.

Comment: @vikingosegundo "you also can control-drag to an action declared in a class extension" - really? Nice. I didn't know this. Could you elaborate more on how this is made possible?

Comment: I am not too sure, but I think it is covered in a WWDC 2011 video Modern ObjC

Comment: WWDC 2012 Session 405 «Modern Objective-C»